# why JSON.parse() is not working in my code?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am using Django and trying to get data using javascript directly. Here are some codes. In the idx_map.html, the JS part looks like this:

```
 var act = '{{ activities_json }}';

    document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = act[0];

    var obj = JSON.parse(act);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 1;
```

I am trying to find the bug so I put some codes to output lines to the page. The problem is the `JSON.parse()` line. If I comment that line, I can see [ and 1 in my HTML page, which means no bugs yet. But if I uncomment the `JSON.parse()` line, I cannot see 1 anymore, indicating the `JSON.parse()` code has some error. But I did not find anything wrong. Could someone help me with that?

In the views.py, I serialize the object into a json file. The codes are:

```
def map(request):
activities_json = serializers.serialize("json", Activities.objects.all())
context = {
    "activities": Activities.objects.all(),
    "activities_json": activities_json,
}
return render(request, "CS_Activities/idx_map.html", context)
```

So the act should look like this (as a string?):

```
[
    {"model": "CS_Activities.activities", "pk": 1, "fields": {"act_name": "gun shot", "location": "York Universitty", "loc_lat": 43.76776, "loc_long": -79.50297, "time": "2018-11-05T20:25:08Z", "description": "a people dead"}}, {"model": "CS_Activities.activities", "pk": 2, "fields": {"act_name": "another gun shot", "location": "York Village", "loc_lat": 43.76, "loc_long": -79.5, "time": "2018-11-05T22:35:06Z", "description": "A person shot dead while walking"}}
]
```

Updates: 
In the idx_map.html, if I just replace the var act as the long string, there would be no errors. So I think the problem in my case is how to retrieve the data from the Django database as a json file format.

Comment: `'{{ activities_json }}'` is not valid json but your later example seems to be.

Comment: You should be able to print the server side json directly without wrapping quotes around it and not need to use JSON.parse(). Then the javascript compiler would see something like `var act = [{"model".... ]` and it would already be javascript array

Comment: Try using `'{{ activities_json|safe }}'`. toString() is not necessary, it's already a string.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python` and `django`?

Comment: Matthias, I am using Django. In the views.py, I serialize the object to JSON in order to use it in javascript in the HTML page. That's why I use act = '{{ activities_json }}'  to query the data.

Comment: @XuyangHan, are you sure you'll have access to the `document` API on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `safe` which marks the string (or JSON in this case) as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.

```
var act = '{{ activities_json|safe }}';
```

This part of the code:

```
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = act[0];
```

just gets the first element of the string, which is [.

This part of the code

```
var obj = JSON.parse(act);
```

returns error, because you didn't use `safe` previously and quote (") is output as `&quote;` in the template which is invalid. I guess you want something like this:

```
var act = '{{ activities_json|safe }}';
var lat = 43.767760;
var lng = -79.502970;
var latLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};       

var obj = JSON.parse(act);
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = obj[0];
```

Now `obj[0]` will return first JSON element, but I'm not sure what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Tried to add safe but still not working. I updated my question, would you mind taking another look? thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? It's not just the `safe` that you need to add, you need to change act[0] to obj[0], too, and parse string to JSON before that.